# Cannot implement TabBarIOS due to TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I cannot impelment TabBarIOS. The code below renders an "Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined"

I have minimal dependencies
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.1"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { 
  TabBarIOS,
  View, 
  Text 
} from 'react-native'; 


export default class HomeScreen extends Component { 
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
      tab: 'newsFeed' 
    }; 
  } 
  render() {  

    return ( 
      <TabBarIOS>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          systemIcon={'featured'} 
          selected={this.state.tab === 'newsFeed'} 
          onPress={() => this.setState({ tab: 'newsFeed' })}
        >
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </TabBarIOS.Item> 
      </TabBarIOS>
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: FWIW If I remove the items and run only the TabBarIOS I get an ElementType is invalid error (expected a string for built ins or class/func for composite but got undefined

Comment: TabBarIOS has been removed from React Native in v0.59, I have created an
alternative component from it! May help you!
[react-native-tabbar-ios](https://github.com/TranLuongTuanAnh/react-native-tabbar-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TabBarIOS has been removed from React Native in v0.59, per [this unofficial changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Isn’t that the official changelog?

Comment: Its still in the docs. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios     hmmm now what to use?

Comment: @Andrew as official as it gets, apparently

Comment: @ManuelHernandez it looks like may have been removed along with a number of other platform-specific components as part of a refactor, and the docs haven't been updated yet. I can't figure out what they were planning to do with it